# Fortran serialization using C_LOC and C_F_POINTER

Tags: serialization, fortran, fortran2003

I'm looking for a Fortran Library or preferred method of serializing data to a memory buffer in Fortran.

After researching the topic, I found examples using the EQUIVALENCE statement and the TRANSFER intrinsic function. I wrote code to test them and they both worked. In my limited testing, the transfer function seems to be quite a bit slower than the equivalence statement. However, I have found several references stating that in general not to use the equivalence statement.

So, I've been trying to come up with another way to serialize data efficiently. After ready up on the Fortran 2003 spec I discovered that I could use the C_LOC and C_F_POINTER together to cast my "byte" array into the desired data type (int, real, etc..). Initial testing shows that it is working and is faster than the transfer function. An example program is listed below. I was wondering if this is valid use of the C_LOC and C_F_POINTER functions.

Thanks!

```
  program main
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none


    real(c_float)             :: a, b, c
    integer(c_int8_t), target :: buf(12)

    a = 12345.6789_c_float
    b = 4567.89123_c_float
    c = 9079.66788_c_float

    call pack_float( a, c_loc(buf(1)) )
    call pack_float( b, c_loc(buf(5)) )
    call pack_float( c, c_loc(buf(9)) )

    print '(A,12I5)', 'Bin: ', buf


  contains


    subroutine pack_float( src, dest )
      implicit none
      real(c_float), intent(in) :: src
      type(c_ptr), intent(in)   :: dest
      real(c_float), pointer    :: p
      call c_f_pointer(dest, p)
      p = src
    end subroutine


  end program
```

Output:

```
Bin:   -73  -26   64   70   33  -65 -114   69  -84  -34   13   70
```

I also coded this up in Python to double check the answer above. The code and output is listed below.

```
import struct

a = struct.pack( '3f', 12345.6789, 4567.89123, 9079.66788)
b = struct.unpack('12b', a)
print b
```

Output:

```
(-73, -26, 64, 70, 33, -65, -114, 69, -84, -34, 13, 70)
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do ?  I'm probably dim but to me 'serialisation' suggests taking a complex data structure, probably one comprising a graph- or tree-like structure of components, and transforming it into a sequence of elements (possibly bytes) for storage or transfer.  3 Fortran reals hardly need to be serialised.

Comment: I can't find any question in your post. BTW a derived type can be written to output directly if it dies not contain pointers or allocatables.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  First, thanks for taking time to comment. What am I trying to do? Log data as efficiently as possible in an application that has a real time operating constraint. File i/o is too costly. Data is currently stored in a memory buffer and flushed to a file once the run has completed. Current process only allows the storage of scalar 32bit integer and real variables.
My code sample above was meant to be very simple. Trying to determine if c_loc and c_f_pointer can be used this way (I’m I going to run into a road block later on using this method?).

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for taking time to comment; I’ve learned a great deal from your other posts/comments. My intended question was – is it valid to use c_loc and c_f_pointer to point into a buffer and “cast” it to store different fortran types (1|2|4|8 byte ints & floats, fixed arrays, etc). I have a mixture of derived types; many are fixed, but some have dynamic fields.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Ok; I wasn’t able to find any methods from my initial research. It “does” feel odd to me as well! I’ve not been in the programming arena very long but it seems like all the serialization libraries are in other programming languages. I actually wrote some test code to output data using the XDR and Protobuf protocols in Fortran for a couple derived types. XDR seems to be more fitting for my use case. I just don’t want to have to force everything to big endian. Thought about using XDR spec but making it little endian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically, use of C_LOC and C_F_POINTER in this way is likely to work, but formally it is not standard conforming.  The type and type parameters of the Fortran pointer passed to C_F_POINTER must either be interoperable with the object nominated by the C address or be the same as the type and type parameters of the object that was originally passed to C_LOC (see the description of the FPTR argument in F2008 15.2.3.3).  Depending on what you are trying to serialize, you may also find that formal restrictions on the C_LOC argument (which are progressively less restrictive in later standards than F2003) come into play.

(The C equivalent requires use of unsigned char for this sort of trick - which is not necessarily the same thing as int8_t.)

There are constraints on the items in an EQUIVALENCE set that make that approach not generally applicable (see constraints C591 through C594 in F2008).  Interpreting the internal representation of an object through equivalence is also formally subject to the rules around definition and undefinition of variables - see F2008 16.6.6 item 1 in particular.

The conforming way to access the representation of one object as a different type in Fortran is through TRANSFER.  Be mindful that serialization of the internal representation of derived types with allocatable or pointer components (is that what you mean by dynamic fields?) may not be useful.

Depending on circumstance, it may be simpler and more robust to simply store your real time results in an array of the type of the thing to be stored.

Comment: This is what I needed to know! Your spec references were very helpful. Using them I was able to find a couple Intel Fortran forum posts that aided in my understanding and usage of both Transfer and Equivalence. I’ll go back and reconsider my design/options; and as/when necessary use Transfer. Thanks!